# Regular expression for hyphen in password

Tags: java, regex

want to allow hyphen in password validation, below are the cases-
1. must contain mixed case
2. length must be 8 to 32
3. at least one special character. (only that are visible on keyboard).

I have made it,
`((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_'\"+={};:<>,.?/]).{8,32})`
but it does not allow `hyphen`, so where to put `hyphen` so it includes hyphen in special character set.

Comment: `I have made it` -- Please show it. Also this might be a [fun reading](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/33471).

Comment: If your current regex matches everything correctly except for hyphen, just add it to the very end of your special characters set, right before the closing ]

Comment: A max length for passwords is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably build a regex that does all the checks in one go, but I would suggest the following approach instead:

```java
private static boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    boolean valid = true;
    // at least one lowercased char
    valid &= password.matches(".*[a-z].*");
    // at least one uppercased char
    valid &= password.matches(".*[A-Z].*");
    // at least one digit
    valid &= password.matches(".*[0-9].*");
    // at least one special char
    valid &= password.matches(".*[!@#$%^&*()_'\"+={};:<>,.?/-].*");
    // length & no other char
    valid &= password.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_'\"+={};:<>,.?/-]{8,32}");
    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow hyphen `-` in your character class.

Try this regex:

```
^(?=.*?\\d)(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[!@#$%^&*()_'\"+={};:<>,.?/-]).{8,32})$
```